# how to acces value from outside if statement

Tags: java, arduino, processing

How to access var value from out side of `if` statement. I want to access `brightestX` value from outside of `if(video.available)` statement.

```cpp
void draw(){
  if (video.available()) 
  {
    video.read();
    image(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    int brightestX = 0; 
    int brightestY = 0; 
    float brightestValue = 0; 

    video.loadPixels();
    int index = 0;
   
    for ( int y = 0; y < video.height; y++) {
        for ( int x = 0; x < video.width; x++) {
          int pixelValue = video.pixels[index];
          float pixelBrightness = brightness(pixelValue);

          if (pixelBrightness > brightestValue) {
              brightestValue = pixelBrightness;        
              brightestY = y;
              brightestX = x;
          }
          index++;
        }
    }
    fill(255, 204, 0, 128);
    ellipse(brightestX, brightestY, 200, 200);  
  }
}
```

Comment: It's explained in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It's a Q&A site, like a wiki for questions and their answers. So if someone has a question that was solved before, they can easily find some Stack Overflow answer on Google this way.

Comment: @CherryDT did you think my sentence not include a question?

Comment: It's "a question", but not really a [good one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in my opinion. And my comment was referring to "so what does SO mean" which itself was a response to you saying "hi forum can you help me". The question as it is now is not really actionable for us, there is no "next step" to take from here without further information. The issue could very well also be on the Arduino side, but you didn't show the code for it nor how you connected the Servo. But that doesn't mean that you should dump that code here now as well, because it's just a lot of noise that [...]

Comment: [...] obscures the actually relevant parts of the situation. The key is to create a minimal reproducible example (as explained in the link I just shared). By doing that, you cut away everything that's irrelevant for the problem and narrow it down to the one problematic operation. That helps both of us to get closer to a solution. By the way, for such Arduino-specific questions, it may be better to ask on https://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: @CherryDT thank you for your suggestion. but my question really has clear scope. also its clear i marked not only arduino, proccesing and java include

Comment: @Enthusiast if you declare and initialize your variables *before* the "if", they'll be accessible from the outer scope.

Comment: BTW I think the question is perfectly valid, framed, understandable and eligible for an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare the variables you want to access outside the scope of the `if` condition.

You can reference the same variables later inside the `if` condition to update them, then after the `if` you can read these updated values.

Of course these values will only be updated while video data is available (otherwise remain as the most recently updated values):

```java
void draw(){
  int brightestX = 0; 
  int brightestY = 0; 
    
  if (video.available()) 
  {
    video.read();
    image(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    float brightestValue = 0; 

    video.loadPixels();
    int index = 0;

    for ( int y = 0; y < video.height; y++) {
        for ( int x = 0; x < video.width; x++) {
          int pixelValue = video.pixels[index];
          float pixelBrightness = brightness(pixelValue);

          if (pixelBrightness > brightestValue) {
              brightestValue = pixelBrightness;        
              brightestY = y;
              brightestX = x;
          }
          index++;
        }
    }
    fill(255, 204, 0, 128);
    ellipse(brightestX, brightestY, 200, 200);  
  }
  
  println(brightestX, brightestY); 
    
}
```

If it helps, also check out [Java Scope](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope).